# Is there a way to do convolution or fully connection at the third dimension channel?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

Recently, I'm trying to implement a simple neural network for my extracted features.
So what I'd like the neural network to do for me is as below:

Once an image passes through the encoder, the corresponding embedding of that image is obtained.
The embedding's shape and visualization is as follow:
[Visualization of image's embedding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBDFS.png)

, which the 13*13 gray area stands for small patches that construct the whole image and 64 means flattened pixel value for each small patches. In other words, an image will be divided into 13*13 (169) small patches and each patches pixel is flattened to 64 values, forming the third dimension of this block.

So my goal for this task is that I'd like to construct a neural network which is able to calculate a scalar score for each patch, meaning that for this entire image, the NN will calculate score for each gray little patch, so for each image, there would be in total 169 scalar score.

In order to do so, I've tried to do convolution over the third dimension:
This is my training function:

```
for epoch in range(epochs):
    model.train()
    for i, sample in enumerate(train_loader):
        fe, target = sample['fe'], sample['label']   # fe shape: (64, 13, 13, 64)
        fe = np.transpose(fe, (0, 3, 1, 2))
        fe = fe.cuda()    # (64, 64, 13, 13)
        target = target.cuda()
        output = model(fe)
        ...
```

This is my model:

```
class ADModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ADModel, self).__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=1, kernel_size=1, padding=0)
   
    def forward(self, feature):    
        scores = self.conv(feature)
```

and also, I've tried to place a fully connected layer with input channel 64 and output channel 1. Yet, both of these trials seemed to be unable to convolve at the right dimension and for fully connected approach, I barely have idea about how to do so. :(
So I'm currently wondering if there's other better ways to achieve what I'm expecting to do or if my assumption at first is wrong.

Thank you for reading until here, I'm really appreciated!

Comment: So each one of the 169 "patches" gets projected separately from the 64-feature space to a singleton logit?

Comment: @Ivan Yes! Exactly!

Comment: Ok. Your figure doesn't match the shape of `fe`, are you sure it is not `(64, 64, 13, 13)`?

Comment: @Ivan Oh yes, the embedding from the encoder is (64, 13, 13, 64), but in order to place it into the model, I transpose it to (64, 64, 13, 13).

Comment: And that is not working for you?